# Facebook fbAsyncInit not loading when all.js loaded before

Tags: javascript, facebook

I built module which displays FB like button on site. It works fine excepting when there is `<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` loaded before on the same page. If all.js is loaded before, fbAsyncIniti will never be triggered.

My code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<li class="fbLike">
  <div data-share="false" data-show-faces="false" data-layout="box_count" data-href="<?php echo $share_url?>" data-action="like" class="fb-like"></div>
</li>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'APP_ID',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.1'
  });       
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 
</script>
```

It will work if I remove `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {` from the code. But this is not solution because I don't know if customer have all.js loaded before or not. I could check with jQuery if this script is already inside DOM, but this is still not proper solution because script can be inside DOM but not loaded yet.

What would be proper method to check if all.js was loaded before so I can remove `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {` only in such case? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Well you could check if the global `FB` object already exists …

Comment: This is also what I thought, I will probably just use this `if(window.FB){`, I guess it should be enough.